# Upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04 on Dell Inspiron 1440 Laptop

Tags: 12.04

Is it possible to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 on Dell inspiron 1440 Model PP42L?

Comment: Are you asking for instructions on how to perform the upgrade? Or if Ubuntu 14.04 will be compatible with your system? Please be more specific, as the answer to your question is currently just "Yes".

Comment: I tried your upgrade advice which worked well. However, Ubuntu gave me a notice that the graphics card on my old computer could not handle Unity 3D properly and if I continued my computer might slow down a lot. It advised me to stay with 12.04, which I did. How to proceed now?? Does this mean that I will not be able to upgrade to 14.04!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to.

Here are some guides:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes#General_Upgrade_Information

Since you are having graphics problems.

You can install kde 4.12 easily on ubuntu 14.04 , open terminal :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Ubuntu gave me a notice that the graphics card on my old computer could not handle Unity 3D properly and if I continued my computer might slow down a lot. It advised me to stay with 12.04, which I did. How to proceed now?? Does this mean that I will not be able to upgrade to 14.04!!

Comment: @VURao you can install a different Desktop Manager if you wish to go to 14.04.  Such as Gnome (http://www.gnome.org/) or KDE (http://www.kde.org/) which are generally lighter and won't place a strain on your computer like Unity does.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I shall be grateful to you if you can give me step by step procedure to install lighter version which won't place strain on my laptop Dell Inspiron 1440.

Comment: @VURao hopefully you find this helpful: http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-kde-4-13-in-ubuntu-14-04/